# Finding the sum of the infinite series whose general term is not easy to visualize: $\frac16+\frac5{6\cdot12}+\frac{5\cdot8}{6\cdot12\cdot18}+\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am to find out the sum of infinite series:-
$$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6\cdot12}+\frac{5\cdot8}{6\cdot12\cdot18}+\frac{5\cdot8\cdot11}{6\cdot12\cdot18\cdot24}+...............$$
I can not figure out the general term of this series. It is looking like a power series as follows:-
$$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6^2\cdot2!}+\frac{5\cdot8}{6^3\cdot3!}+\frac{5\cdot8\cdot11}{6^4\cdot4!}+.....$$
So how to solve it and is there any easy way to find out the general term of such type of series?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you write $6.12$, you mean multiplication $6$ times $12$, yeah?

Comment: Apart from the first term which doesn't follow the pattern, it appears that each additional term is of the form $\frac{1}{6}\prod\limits_{n=0}^k\frac{3n+5}{6n+12}$.  The missing fifth entry by this pattern would be $\frac{5\cdot 8\cdot 11\cdot 14}{6\cdot 12\cdot 18\cdot 24\cdot 30}$, etc...  Without knowing exactly where the sequence comes from, it is not guaranteed however that this actually *is* the pattern, it is just a guess.  If that is the case, then it will converge slightly faster than a geometric series with $r=\frac{1}{2}$, so it should be able to be approximated.

Comment: yes.....if there is any confusion i may edit it

Comment: @JMoravitz: The first term does fit the pattern: it's $1/6$ times the empty product.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'm sure there are many more. Aside from your example, I find at least two more similar questions (excluding those that has been marked as duplicate). I still haven't find the one which I vaguely remember. I wish math.SE has a better search engine.

Comment: This is a [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: this is not an answerable question

Comment: I was just asking that is there any non-deterministic way to solve these types of series sum?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936146/sum-of-the-infinite-series-frac16-frac56-cdot-12-frac5-cdot86-cdot1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice $$
\begin{align}
  & \frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6\cdot 12} + \frac{5\cdot 8}{6\cdot 12\cdot 18} + \cdots\\
= & \frac12 \left[ \frac{3-1}{6} + \frac{(3-1)(6-1)}{6^2 \cdot 2!} + \frac{(3-1)(6-1)(9-1)}{6^33!} + \cdots\right]\\
= & \frac12 \left[ \frac{\frac23}{2} + \frac{\frac23(\frac23+1)}{2^2\cdot 2!}
+ \frac{\frac23(\frac23+1)(\frac23+2)}{2^3\cdot 3!} + \cdots \right]
\end{align}
$$
The sum we want has the form
$\displaystyle\;\frac12 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\prod_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(\frac23 + \ell)}{2^k k!}$.
Compare this with the expansion

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha)_k}{k!} z^k
\quad\text{ where }\quad
(\alpha)_k = \prod\limits_{\ell=0}^{k-1}( \alpha + \ell )$$

We find the desired sum equals to
$$\frac12 \left[\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac12\right)^{2/3}} - 1\right] = \frac12\left( 2^{2/3} - 1 \right)
\approx 
0.293700525984...
$$

**Notes**

After I finish this answer, I have a déjà vu feeling that I have seen this before
(more than once).
Following are some similar questions I can locate, I'm sure there are more...

- [Sum of a Hyper-geometric series. (NBHM 2011)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/635315/59379)
- [Find a closed form for this infinite sum: $ 1+\frac 1 2 +\frac{1 \times2}{2 \times 5}+\frac{1 \times2\times 3}{2 \times5\times 8}+ \dots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/889117/59379)
- [Calculating $1+\frac13+\frac{1\cdot3}{3\cdot6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3\cdot6\cdot9}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot12}+\dots? $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/746388/59379)

Comment: how come I have a déjà vu feeling that I have seen this before???

Comment: It is a question from NBHM 2011 sample paper ,so it is quite possible you may have seen it before

Comment: The general term can be made anything we want it to be, this is same as given a finite sequence trying to guess the next term. without the explicit formula for the general term or some recursive way of defining the terms it is just waste of time to guess the general fprm.

Answer (score 4):

Let us consider $$\Sigma=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6\times 12}+\frac{5\times8}{6\times12\times18}+\frac{5\times8\times11}{6\times12\times18\times24}+\cdots$$ and let us rewrite it as $$\Sigma=\frac{1}{6}+\frac 16\left(\frac{5}{ 12}+\frac{5\times8}{12\times18}+\frac{5\times8\times11}{12\times18\times24}+\cdots\right)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac 16 \sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n$$ using $$S_n=\frac{\prod_{i=0}^n(5+3i)}{\prod_{i=0}^n(12+6i)}$$ Using the properties of the gamma function, we have $$\prod_{i=0}^n(5+3i)=\frac{5\ 3^n \Gamma \left(n+\frac{8}{3}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{8}{3}\right)}$$ $$\prod_{i=0}^n(12+6i)=6^{n+1} \Gamma (n+3)$$ which make $$S_n=\frac{5\ 2^{-n-1} \Gamma \left(n+\frac{8}{3}\right)}{3 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{8}{3}\right) \Gamma (n+3)}$$ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n=\frac{10 \left(3\ 2^{2/3}-4\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{9 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{8}{3}\right)}=3\ 2^{2/3}-4$$ $$\Sigma=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

It seems like (without knowing the exact form we can not proceed) the **double of $n$th term** of your series is given by $$u_n=\dfrac{2.5.8.11\cdots(3n-1)}{6.12.18.24\cdots(6n)}.$$ By ratio test this series is convergent and we can find the exact formula for $n$th partial summation $\sum^{n}_{r=1} u_r$ by observing $$(6n+6)u_{n+1}=u_n(3n+2)\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Find a function $f$ with the property $$f(r+1)=f(r)\left(\dfrac{3r+2}{6r+6}\right)$$ (in terms of $u_r$) and $$u_r=f(r)-f(r+1).$$ Then Telescope to find $\sum^{n}_{r=1} u_r$.

Answer (score 3):

This is $\frac{1}{2} \left(_2F_1(2/3,1;1;\frac{1}{2}) - 1\right)$ where $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function. For these parameters this evaluates to $\frac{1}{2} \left(_2F_1(2/3,1;1;\frac{z}{2}) - 1\right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( (1 - \frac{z}{2})^{-2/3} - 1\right)$.